# Invalid credentials problem when consumig tone analizer from a nodejs app

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, tone-analyzer

I'm trying to consume a tone analyzer service from a nodejs app. I get unauthorized access problem, but these credentials work fine when I use them in a curl.

Running locally, in my app.js file I've included the data of the tone analyzer as follows:

```
var ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');

var toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
  version: '2017-09-21',
  iam_apikey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
```

Then I've added this, so my app listens for post requestes in the /tone url:

```
app.post('/tone', function(req, res, next) {

    var params = {'tone_input': req.body}

    toneAnalyzer.tone(params, function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    return res.json(data);
  });
});
```

But when I call it I get "Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials".

The thing is that these credentials work fine in curl:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @tone.json "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&sentences=false"
```

```
{"document_tone":{"tones":[{"score":0.6165,"tone_id":"sadness","tone_name":"Sadness"},{"score":0.829888,"tone_id":"analytical","tone_name":"Analytical"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting unauthorised errors when running locally is that your service is hosted in `https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net`. If you don't specify an endpoint / url in your `ToneAnalyzerV3` constructor then the API / SDK defaults to `Dallas`. So although your credentials may be correct for `London`, they are not correct for `Dallas`.

When you deployed your app to the cloud (which I guess was to the London location), you probably bound the service into your application. This sets environment variables allowing the SDK to determine the endpoint.

You constructor should look like:

```js
var toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
  version: '2017-09-21',
  iam_apikey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  url: 'https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api',
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see problem with code (also never used watson stuff),  but you may check the following point :

- How the request you really send is formated : Because I see that you send param that is not present in your curl request.
- Is your function using POST aswell (you don't provide much detail on what the call to toneAnalyzer.tone does exactly)  ? Maybe it's a conflict of headers or Content-Type.
- Do you use a proxy (enterprise settings or stuff like that) ? If you do, you may check that node is correctly using it.

You should also provide a bit more details on what exactly your tone object do, and try to find where the call to the IBM API is done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I deployed the app to IBM Cloud and it works. Seems there was a problem with my computer

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of the tone analyser stuff :). Have a good day